# autocomplete path in cmd batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Windows CMD prompt's auto-complete, (similar feature in other terminals), comes very handy sometimes when you are not sure of the right path or file name.

---

Bottom line is, how to use this feature in batch scripting.

 Example: 
 the script 
 `"C:\Program Files\Java\`**`jre1.8.0_92`**`\bin\javaw.exe" -jar post.jar`

the thing here is that java version is not always the same, so it needed to be something like this 
 `"C:\Program Files\Java\`**`jre*`**`\bin\javaw.exe" -jar post.jar`

Comment: There is no such auto-complete feature in cmd. What would this mean if there were multiple directories that match `jre*`? The closest thing that comes to this would be to get the desired JRE directory into the PATH variable. Then, you would not specify a directory path to javaw.exe.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to say

Comment: You can parameterize the version above and simply inject that into the path to the executable, if you wish.

Comment: Code's purpose is to auto find the right path, as the example of java version, just to make it a general code, parameterizing weakens it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use wildcards in the middle of a path, but you can at the end (the last element). Because you need it in between, split it up:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on "C:\Program Files\Java\jre*"') do set ver=%%a
set "exec=C:\Program Files\Java\%ver%\javaw.exe"
"%exec%" -jar post.jar
```

This will get you the path with the highest version number, if there are more than one.

Comment: there's just one thing, last command  should be "%exec%" -jar post.jar

Comment: This is based on the assumption that the "highest" version number is the correct one to use. Often, this is not the case.

Comment: as long as OP does not tell us, which version to use (or if there are more than one), we have to assume... (and you are right with the quotes around `highest` because of string comparison: `1.8.0_92 > 1.8.0_121`)

Answer (score 0):

[Wildcards are supported by only some commands](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html). Moreover, `cmd` restricts wildcards in a file path only in a path *leaf*  i.e. in token behind last backslash…

On an *unknown* Windows system: if you do not have control on environment variables then you need to *find* a file path e.g. as follows (note the `_checkPath` variable assignment is changed to get reasonable output as I do not have `java` installed):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    rem assign path with a wildcard * not in path leaf 
set "_checkPath=C:\Program Files\Java\jre*\bin\javaw.exe"
    rem delete or comment-up next line i.e. my test data      set "_checkPath=..." 
set "_checkPath=%ProgramFiles%*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr%1.exe"
set "_itemFirst="
    rem previous line: delete variable; next line: show setting
set _checkPath
echo(---
    rem next two lines: ensure that a wildcard * not in path leaf is not allowed
echo dir /B /S "%_checkPath%"
dir /B /S "%_checkPath%"
echo(---
    rem find all files by parsing powershell output ( note proper escaping ^^^| )
for /F "usebackq tokens= 1* delims=: " %%G in (`
  powershell -C Get-ChildItem '"%_checkPath%"' -Recurse ^^^| Format-List -Property FullName
  `) do (
        rem assign first found item
    if not defined _itemFirst set "_itemFirst=%%~H"
        rem assign every found item thus last found item
    set "_item_Last=%%~H"
        rem show every found item
    echo .exe found %%~H
)
echo(---
    rem show setting found
set _item
echo(---
if defined _itemFirst (
    echo success: "%_checkPath%"
        rem commands are merely ECHOed and (my test data) commented up 
        rem use found items (choose any)
    rem ECHO "%_itemFirst%" -jar post.jar
    rem ECHO "%_item_Last%" -jar post.jar
) else (
    echo NOT FOUND "%_checkPath%"
)
```

Above code snippet is richly commented where necessary for better understanding. 
**Output** shows both variants:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\38281447.bat XXX
_checkPath=C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservrXXX.exe
---
dir /B /S "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservrXXX.exe"
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
---
---
Environment variable _item not defined
---
NOT FOUND "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservrXXX.exe"

==> D:\bat\SO\38281447.bat
_checkPath=C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
---
dir /B /S "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe"
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
---
.exe found C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
.exe found C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
.exe found C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
---
_itemFirst=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
_item_Last=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe
---
success: "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server\1*\LocalDB\Binn\sqlservr.exe"

==>
```